# sql server backup

Tags: sql-server, backup-restoration

Is there any way to to restore a backup created on sql server 2005, onto sql server 2000?

Edit: all I have is the .bak file, no access to the original database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  The database formats are incompatible.  You should be able to restore it to a SQL 2005 instance and then copy it to the 2000 instance via the copy db wizard.

Comment: I'll add that you can get a 60 trial version of SQL 2008 from MSFT's website.

Comment: Yeah, or SQL Express for free if all you need is something to restore to.  And as long as the db is small enough.